# Check if MongoDB is connected to MongoDB Atlas

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

I want to do a text search in MongoDB. In development I use a local mongodb, and in production I use MongoDB Atlas. I want to do a `$search` Atlas Search if the db I am connected to is MongoDB Atlas. If I'm connected to a local db I want to use `$text`.

### What I've considered

#### Check the connection uri

If it ends with `.mongodb.net`, use Atlas Search. If not, use normal text search.

#### Try using $search, then if error use $text

In production it won't be slow because first it will attempt `$search` and it will work in production. In development it might be slow because of making an extra failing query every time.

### Also

Is there a way of mimicking the Atlas search behavior for a local MongoDB? It's okay if it involves a really slow query but it would be nice to test with same quality text matching as there will be in production.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to use atlas search with local db. `If it ends with .mongodb.net, use Atlas Search.` - you also can look at connection string schema whether it's `mongodb+srv:` or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say both of your suggestions are considered anti patterns and I would personally avoid both.

What I would personally do is very similar to your first suggestion but instead of checking the value of the connection string I would just use the `process.env.NODE_ENV` value, this is considered common practice to use this to separate between your dev staging and prod enviorments.

---

> Is there a way of mimicking the Atlas search behavior for a local MongoDB? It's okay if it involves a really slow query but it would be nice to test with same quality text matching as there will be in production.

Technically no, as you know atlas search gives you many search engine abilities such as tokenizers and analyzers out of the box. If you have a very specific use case maybe you could engineer a solution to make it work, but that will require you to basically reverse engineer the functionality you're using through atlas which means it's probably not worth the effort.

**Edit:**

Recently MongoDB added the options for a local atlas deployment, you can follow these [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/atlas-cli-deploy-local/).